# It is possible to create a test plan with INSERT operations? for a MySQL Server with 1.000 records on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, test-plan

Im new with this tool and i dont know exactly how this work, somebody can illustrate me?
Thanks in advance!
Regards!

Comment: those 1.000 records are irrelevant, excuse me :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and copy the .jar to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan.
3. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) to your Thread Group and specify your database URL, JDBC driver type (which is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for MySQL) and the "Variable Name" setting to anything meaningful.
4. Add [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to the Thread Group, change "Query Type" to `Update Statement` or `Prepared Update Statement` depending on the query you need to simulate.
5. Put your SQL query into the sampler
6. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to be able to see the generate query and results (don't forget to disable or delete it during the real load test)

More information:

- [Building a Database Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection)